# I am installing Linux Lite and want to use a HDD with existing data that I don't want to lose. What are my next steps?

Tags: linux, partition, system-installation

I also do not need to dual boot into windows or any other OS. I only want Linux installed. I am uncertain of the steps and can't find clarity on this point. Any help at all is appreciated.

I have installed this ISO before, but used an empty HDD previously. Now, I want to use an existing HDD with data on it that I do not want to lose. There are no other operating systems on this computer and no need for dual booting.

I have not tried to install it again because I do not know if it will harm the existing data.

- Do I unmount the disks when asked?
- Do I specify a new partition?
- The drive currently has two partitions, a large one with the data I want to keep and a small one that I think was for the former OS. Can I use the small one for my install? If not, how can I get rid of the smaller partition?

Comment: If it's data you want to keep, the first step should always be to back it up first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.

Once the installer asks where to install the OS just specify the partition you want to use. If it is a small one - not really a problem, as long as it is large enough for the new OS.

Even better/easier solution would be to have a second HDD. Install the new OS on it - and mount the old one as a secondary. This way you can copy/move all the staff you need from the old drive. And you can do it any time after install is complete and new OS is running smoothly.

If your machine is a laptop and cannot handle two drives - you can buy an "external hdd enclosure" and use it for secondary HDD.

Comment: I feel like "just specify the partition you want to use" is open to misinterpretation, with some installers this could end up having the partition used, but the filesystem reformatted, losing all of the data on it.